# cURL 28 error. network issue?

Tags: wordpress, curl

I am in the process of learning to use Wordpress and am hosting sites locally so that I can practice.

I am, however, getting an error whenever I try and install a new theme or plug-in. The error is as follows:

"cURL error 28: Operation timed out after **0** milliseconds with 0 bytes received."

I do not have this issue when I am at my parent's house but I do have this issue when I'm at my apartment which makes me think it's some kind of connectivity or network issue specific to my residence but I have no idea how to go about figuring that out or fixing the problem.

Any thoughts/help would be greatly appreciated. It has been over a week now of trying to figure out some kind of resolution.

Comment: What are your local environment specs? OS, WAMP/XAMP etc?

Comment: Mac OS. I'm using a program called Local by Flywheel which allows local site hosting. However I had previously tried both XAMP and WAMP and was getting the same error.  As I said, I don't get the error when I am at my parents house on their internet but I do get the error when I'm at home on my own network.

Comment: Check what DNS you're using and change to another DNS and see if the issue gets resolved. Check this [tutorial](http://osxdaily.com/2015/12/05/change-dns-server-settings-mac-os-x/) for DNS help on Mac.

Comment: I believe I changed my DNS and the issue is still present. If I connect my computer to the hotspot from my phone then I have no issue. So it's specific to my internet connection here at my apartment. I don't know where to go from here. It's particularly strange that the error I'm getting is referencing 0 milliseconds.